# Can somebody explain me what this VBA code means?

Tags: vba, excel

This is for an excel with macros. I am really lost here. I'd really appreciate any help.

```
Sheets("5. Resume").Select

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "'Tarea IS'[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotSelect "'Tarea IS'[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

Sheets("6. Reg Err").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Simple google search `Pivot Tables excel vba` will give you plenty of results. This [link](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables) will give you kick start.

Comment: It's refreshing pivot table results.

Comment: "Refresh"es pivot tables, Pivottable1 and Pivottable2

Comment: @ManishChristian How is it helpful to respond to a specific question with a generic link about random VBA pivot examples??

Comment: @Rory, the link will help him understand the basics of pivot table and hence these lines of code.

Comment: @Macro Man @ Nathan_Sav Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @ManishChristian On that basis I could answer half the questions here just with a link to the VBA language specification. ;)

Comment: You could answer whatever you think is right. I did because I believe it's better to understand than just getting the answer.

Comment: "Give a man a fish..." ;)

Comment: I always prefer the saying "Give a man a fire and he'll be warm for a day, set a man on fire and he'll be warm for life" :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll comment your code for you if this helps:

```
'Select the sheet named "5. Resume"
Sheets("5. Resume").Select

'Select the pivot table named "PivotTable1" on the active sheet ("5. Resume")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "'Tarea IS'[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly, True

'Refresh the data in "PivotTable1" on the selected sheet ("5. Resume") from the source
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

'Select the pivot table named "PivotTable2" on the active sheet ("5. Resume")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotSelect "'Tarea IS'[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly, True

'Refresh the data in "PivotTable1" on the selected sheet ("5. Resume") from the source
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

'Select the sheet named "6. Reg Err"
Sheets("6. Reg Err").Select

'Refresh the data in "PivotTable3" on the selected sheet ("6. Reg Err") from the source
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
```

The lines where you select the pivottable seem to be irrelevant as you are changing the selection shortly after without doing anything to the currently selected item (I am guessing this is recorded). You can remove the lines with `.PivotSelect` and it will not change the outcome.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "'Tarea IS'[All]", _
        xlLabelOnly, True
```

In fact, the following code achieves the same in a much shorter fashion:

```
With Sheets("5. Resume")
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
End With
Sheets("6. Reg Err").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Thank you and all the other helpful commenters. I am sorry if my question was too specific, I am not a VBA programmer.